# The sum of non real roots of the polynomial equation $x^3+3x^2+3x+3=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Problem :

The sum of non real roots of the polynomial equation $x^3+3x^2+3x+3=0$

(a) equals 0

(b) lies between 0 and 1

(c)lies between -1 and 0

(d) has absolute value bigger than 1

My approach :

The discriminant of cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ is given by

$\Delta = 18abcd -4b^3d +b^2c^2 -4ac^3 -27a^2d^2$

$\Delta = -108 < 0 $ Therefore the equation has one real and two non real roots. 
But how to find the roots of this equation not getting any idea please help . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$(x+1)^3=-2,$$
we know one real solution is 
$$x=-1-\sqrt[3]{2}.$$Hence done.

Comment: I deleted my answer anyways.

Comment: I don't think it was necessary to delete your more detailed(than mine)answer.Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The equation can be written as 
$$(x+1)^3=-2.$$
Hence the three roots are $\sqrt[3]2-1$, $\sqrt[3]2\omega-1$, $-\sqrt[3]2\omega-1$, where $\omega$ is a cubic root of unit.